# functional quicktag

Tags: html-editor, quicktag

I want to add quicktags that do more than just add markup. For instance, I  would like to add a quicktag to run a function do apply a js regex on the page content. How can I add a quicktag that executes a function?

To give a specific example, I would like to add a button that removes all markup tags in the entire post text. This is analogous to the predefined quicktags for finding unmatched tags, or "proofread", etc.

Comment: Do you mean shortcode? If so, shortcodes run server-side.

Comment: Can you provide a better example of what you're trying to do? More of a usage case than anything really...

Comment: Sure, I'll expand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example that will add a Quicktag button that calls a Javascript function when it is clicked...

```
<?PHP
function _add_my_quicktags(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    QTags.addButton( 'alert', 'Alert Button', simple_alert );

        function simple_alert() { 
            alert('hello, example callback function');
        }
    </script>
<?php 
}
add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts',  '_add_my_quicktags');
?>
```

UPDATE.... Adding a Callback function that utilizes the passed in variables...

```
    // Add a button called 'abbr' with a callback function
    QTags.addButton( 'abbr', 'Abbr', abbr_prompt );
    // and this is the callback function
    function abbr_prompt(e, c, ed) {
        var prmt, t = this;
        if ( ed.canvas.selectionStart !== ed.canvas.selectionEnd ) {
            // if we have a selection in the editor define out tagStart and tagEnd to wrap around the text
            // prompt the user for the abbreviation and return gracefully on a null input
            prmt = prompt('Enter Abbreviation');
            if ( prmt === null ) return;
            t.tagStart = '<abbr title="' + prmt + '">';
            t.tagEnd = '</abbr>';
        } else if ( ed.openTags ) {
            // if we have an open tag, see if it's ours
            var ret = false, i = 0, t = this;
            while ( i < ed.openTags.length ) {
                ret = ed.openTags[i] == t.id ? i : false;
                i ++;
            }
            if ( ret === false ) {
                // if the open tags don't include 'abbr' prompt for input
                prmt = prompt('Enter Abbreviation');
                if ( prmt === null ) return;
                t.tagStart = '<abbr title="' + prmt + '">';
                t.tagEnd = false;
                if ( ! ed.openTags ) {
                    ed.openTags = [];
                }
                ed.openTags.push(t.id);
                e.value = '/' + e.value;
            } else {
                // otherwise close the 'abbr' tag
                ed.openTags.splice(ret, 1);
                t.tagStart = '</abbr>';
                e.value = t.display;
            }
        } else {
            // last resort, no selection and no open tags
            // so prompt for input and just open the tag
            prmt = prompt('Enter Abbreviation');
            if ( prmt === null ) return;
            t.tagStart = '<abbr title="' + prmt + '">';
            t.tagEnd = false;
            if ( ! ed.openTags ) {
                ed.openTags = [];
            }
            ed.openTags.push(t.id);
            e.value = '/' + e.value;
        }
        // now we've defined all the tagStart, tagEnd and openTags we process it all to the active window
        QTags.TagButton.prototype.callback.call(t, e, c, ed);
    };
```

Comment: What are the callback arguments e, c, and ed?

Comment: @le dorfier Sorry they are not needed, I removed it from my post

Comment: But they might be useful, if they include the textarea content, selected text, etc. Something analogous to a shortcode but without a host trip and js instead of php.

Comment: I have added a new example that uses them

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but a open question from my side and I hope for a answer. I like it to use var inside the function `addButton()`to create the strings inside the callback function dynamicly, like the string on `prmt = prompt('Enter Abbreviation');`. Can you explaine this?

Answer (score 0):

you should write a tinymce plugin, then load it (using tinymce advanced plugin)

Comment: I suspect they only apply to the TinyMCE editor interface. quicktags are for the html editor interface.